# Postgres pg_dump output contains error

Tags: postgresql, import, export, pg-dump

I've inherited a Django/Wagtail CMS and trying to set up the site locally on my mac. I've run pg_dump and when I run the export in Postico (via Load Query) it returns a Syntax error on this line;

```
COPY auth_group (id, name) FROM stdin;
1   Moderators
2   Editors
\.
```

This is the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "1"
LINE 1355: 1 Moderators
```

There are several more blocks that have a similar format further down.

Is this a problem with the way I exported it or do I need to do something different with the way I import it?

Comment: Do you get a similar error when you try to import the dump file using `psql`?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, didn't realise that the export from pg_dump isn't an SQL statement. I managed to get the database in via

psql -u username -d databasename -f pathtofile